# DB2: Recursive Query

Tags: sql, recursion, db2

need help.

Table: M_Objects

```
Col:    Id     Child_Id
Row1    M1       M2
Row2    M3       M4
Row3    M2       M5
Row4    M5       M6
```

I want in my query these results, rows: 1,3,4 when i ask for Id M1.
So for the Id, it should look for child-id and go to id...

```
WITH RPL (oid, ocid) AS
     (  SELECT Upp.ID, Upp.CHILD_ID
        FROM M_ObjectsUpp
        WHERE Upp.ID = 'M1'
      UNION ALL
       SELECT child.ID, child.CHILD_ID
        FROM RPL ab, M_Objects child
        WHERE CHILD.child_id = ab.oid
     )
SELECT *
FROM RPL
```

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing top-down, starting with the ID then taking its child_id to look up the next ID. Thus, you have to change the WHERE in the recursive part to:

```
WITH RPL (oid, ocid) AS
     (  SELECT Upp.ID, Upp.CHILD_ID
        FROM M_Objects Upp
        WHERE Upp.ID = 'M1'
      UNION ALL
       SELECT child.ID, child.CHILD_ID
        FROM RPL ab, M_Objects child
        WHERE CHILD.id = ab.child_id
     )
SELECT *
FROM RPL
```

Comment: except that the field on the right side is ab.ocid

Answer (score 0):

ok works fine, Thanks!
Is it possible to define a condition before first here, that it is only called for first time and not for every recursive run?

```
 SELECT Upp.ID, Upp.CHILD_ID
    FROM M_Objects Upp
    WHERE Upp.ID = 'M1'
```